# remove the subviews from the contentView of UITableViewCell (reset the UITableView)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Any idea on how to reset a `UITableView`?

I want to display a new set of data at the press of a button and also remove all the subviews from the cell's `contentView` and refresh them with a new set of subviews.  I tried `[tableView reloadData]` but the data did get refreshed but the subviews added to the `contentView` of the cells previously persisted.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Better yet, when you create the cell:

```
#define MY_CUSTOM_TAG 1234
mySubview.tag = MY_CUSTOM_TAG;
[cell.contentView addSubview:mySubview] ;
```

And later on, when you need to remove it:

```
[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG]removeFromSuperview] ;
```

Comment: It is applying for the last table view cell and reloading the sub view. all other subviews on others cells are not refreshing

Comment: `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(MY_CUSTOM_TAG)?.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 25):

I got the answer :)

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]) {
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This piece of code will check if the cell's content view has any subviews.
If there are any, it removes them as the for loop iterates!

Comment: decent solution... +1

Comment: It is removing only from the last table view cell, not for all the table view cells

Comment: perfect solution!

Answer (score 16):

Instead of iterating through all the subviews (yourself) to remove them, you can simply do this,

```
[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: That is actually iterating through the subviews to remove them. ;)

Answer (score 3):

cell.contentView.subviews.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperview() }

Comment: This works, except you don't need the parenthesis to wrap a trailing closure, so this simpler form also works: `cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }` works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all the subviews of a UITableViewCell you can use this code:

```
NSArray* subviews = [cell.contentView subviews];
for (UIView* subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Using the code of @leftspin

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but i found a problem with the solution, if you remove one subview from one prototype cell, this view will be removed from all reused cells, this will create a null pointer in the next cell that will be reused.

If you subclass UITableViewCell and remove the subview from there, you will have to do this verification first:

```
if (mySubView != nil ) {
        mySubView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

This also will work inside your cellForRow at indexPath method

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    if (cell.mySubView != nil) {
       cell.mySubView.removeFromSuperview()
     }
    return cell
}
```

Whit this you avoid the null pointer, the code is for swift 3. Hope this help somebody. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.1

```
        let theSubviews: Array = (cell?.contentView.subviews)!
        for view in theSubviews
        {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you try with replace the content but not the UI, for example to a label replace the text:

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell     {

    var firstColumnLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        firstColumnLabel = //create label

        contentView.addSubview(firstColumnLabel)
    }

    func setData(cad: String) {
        firstColumnLabel.text = cad
    }
}
```

and in your tableSource

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell?
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            (cell as! CustomCell).setData(cad: "new value")
        return  cell!
    }
```