# UITableview overwriting on olddata

Tags: ios, uitableview

hi im creating chat example and if user add send button adding new object in my arrray and reload data but its overwrite old table.

[image]

its my array :

```
arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithObjects:@"Whats up today ? ", @"Hello.", nil];
```

Here my source :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simleTableIdentifier = @"TeamCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TeamCell"];
    }


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    UIImageView *myRect = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 10, 12)];
    myRect.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tri.png"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jj.jpg"]];


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    label.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 210, 80);
    [label sizeToFit];

    UIImageView *imgim = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, label.frame.size.width+20, label.frame.size.height+20)];
    imgim.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];

    CGRect myRectANGLE =  CGRectMake(imgim.frame.origin.x+10,imgim.frame.origin.y+10, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);

    [label setFrame:myRectANGLE];

    CALayer *addRadius = [imgim layer];
    [addRadius setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [addRadius setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [self.MyTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.MyTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    self.MyTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1); //in viewDidLoad

    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);//in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:myRect];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:imgim];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}
```

**İf click send button i reload data but its overwite on old-data look like my photo :**

```
-(IBAction)btnTap:(UIButton *)sender {
    [arr1 insertObject:Textify.text atIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%i", arr1.count);
    [MyTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: Try using `addObject` instead of `insertObject: atIndex:`

Comment: Nothing changed. its olready overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the cell's `contentView` subview, and then add the new subviews.

Here's a block of code for removing the subviews, taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759493/remove-the-subviews-from-the-contentview-of-uitableviewcell-reset-the-uitablevi).

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
   for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
       [subview removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

Comment: @omgbbqhax I've updated my answer with a corresponding reference.

Comment: thanks i understood my problem now but i cant add this code in my btnTap action , can i create a new methot and trigger this code with NSNotificationCenter ?

Comment: You should add that on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, right before you add the new subviews.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell will be reused while reload, you should not create subviews again to add on cell.contentView.Try to use code below

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"TeamCell"];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    label.tag = 1000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
}
UILabel *label = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
label.text = @"something";
```