# Deleting a custom view from UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am swiping left to delete a cell that is a customview in Swift 3.

The cell is:

```
class CustomTableCell: SwipeTableViewCell
{
    public var atest = UILabel();
    public var btest = UILabel();

    var animator: Any?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);

        let height = 140;

        atest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 + (activityWidth / 2), y: 72, width: (activityWidth / 2) - 10, height: 30));

        btest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 + (activityWidth / 2), y: 102, width: (activityWidth / 2) - 10, height: 30));

        self.contentView.addSubview(atest);
        self.contentView.addSubview(btest);
    }
```

Then in my table view controller I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableCell;

    cell.atest.text = "text from an array at indexpath.row";
    cell.btest.text = "another different text from an array";

    return cell;
}
```

The deletion in the table view controller happens here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]?
{
    let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete")
    {
        action, indexPath in
        print("delete button tapped");

        // self.table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none);

        // database is a string index array
        self.database.remove(at: indexPath.row);

        if (self.database.count == 0)
        {
            self.noText.isHidden = false;
            self.footer.isHidden = false;

            self.table.tableFooterView = self.footer;
        }

        // self.table.setNeedsDisplay();
    }

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;

    return [delete];
```

I do a delete by swiping left and it deletes everything correctly. The issue I have is that the deleting makes all the table view cells under the fold the same as the last visible cell.

How do I fix this? I am using a custom cell view too.

An example is that I have 6 rows and the top 4 are visible. Deleting the first row makes the 4th and 5th rows the same. As in the last visible row also becomes the first none visible row. The prepareForReuse is probably not working right.

The delete works and goes from 6 rows to 5 but an example is below.

```
 UITableView
 First row label         A
 Second row label        B
 Third row label         C
 Fourth row label        D (last visible row)
 Fifth row label         E (first non visible row)
 Sixth row label         F
```

Deleting the first row by swiping creates this new UITableView:

```
 UITableView
 Second row label        B
 Third row label         C
 Fourth row label        D
 Fourth row label        D (last visible row)
 Fifth row label         E (first non visible row)
```

The reusable cells are not working correctly.

I do not use awakeFromNib and just upgraded to swift 4.1 as well.

Comment: Update your question with the code that handles the deletion.

Comment: I updated the deletion and used https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit to handle swiping

Comment: Unrelated but why don't you design the cell in Interface Builder? And this is Swift: No trailing semicolons and no parentheses around `if` conditions.

Comment: When you delete/remove the cell the custom cell view goes away with it. What do you mean by _The issue I have is that the deleting makes all the table view cells under the fold the same as the last visible cell_? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: They are the rows below the screen that you don't see until they are scrolled to

Comment: Updated the question code with an example.

Comment: Updated with more code for custom cell

Comment: This question is still missing important information. 1. Update to include the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. 2. Post your actual, complete `cellForRowAt` method. 3. Post your actual, complete `editActionsForRowAt` method. The one you posted doesn't even delete a row from the table view. 4. Post your actual, complete `CustomTableCell` class if what you've posted so far isn't actually all of it. And only post one copy. Right now your question includes two separate implementations of `CustomTableCell`. 5. Confirm you are NOT also implementing the `commit editingStyle` data source method.

Comment: Okay deleterowsat never gets called because the swipecellkit handles it so it does a delete.

Comment: Don't use `SwipeTableViewCell`, just extend `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Are you saying drop the plugin? Create it in UITableViewCell.

Comment: I have no idea what the plugin really does but you certainly don't need a library to support standard table view swiping.

Comment: Upgrading to iOS 11 so I can use the trailing and leading functions of UITableView

Answer (score 2):

In `TableView` custom cells if you are adding `views` from `storyboard` or `XIB` then it get removed on scrolling but if you are adding `views` programmatically then you have to remove the view from the `tableViewCell`:

Either using below code in `cellForRow` :

```
for label in cell.subviews {
    if let mylabel = label as? UILabel {
        mylabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

or you can use this code `customCellClass` in `prepareForReuse` method:

```
class myCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

Above code will remove all subviews from the cell.

Check below links for more answers:

- [remove the subviews from the contentView of UITableViewCell (reset the UITableView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759493/remove-the-subviews-from-the-contentview-of-uitableviewcell-reset-the-uitablevi)

**EDIT**

I tried below code with string `Array` and `swipeDelete` functionality in `tableView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTableView: UITableView!

    var nameArray = ["Snoop", "Sarah", "Fido", "Mark", "Jill", "Parague", "London", "Barcelona", "Italy", "France", "Eiffiel", "Tower", "Paris", "Europe", "Amsterdam", "Zurich", "Germany", "Munich", "Milan", "Venice", "Switzerland", "Brussels"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] + " - " + String(describing: indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            nameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

When I start swipe deleting the `tableView` cells the `string` data is correct but the `indexPath` value doesn't change. It changes when I scrolled the `tableView`. Which is correct logically because after deletion the string data indexes have changed and when cells are reused the new index will be visible.

**EDIT Using SwipwCellKit:**

Used the same code of yours with the `SwipeCellKit`:

My `ViewController` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTableView: UITableView!

    var nameArray = ["Snoop", "Sarah", "Fido", "Mark", "Jill", "Parague", "London", "Barcelona", "Italy", "France", "Eiffiel", "Tower", "Paris", "Europe", "Amsterdam", "Zurich", "Germany", "Munich", "Milan", "Venice", "Switzerland", "Brussels"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 72
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableCell

        cell.delegate = self

        cell.atest.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] + " - " + String(describing: indexPath.row)
        cell.btest.text = "another different text from an array";

        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]?
    {
        let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete")
        {
            action, indexPath in
            print("delete button tapped")

            self.nameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            self.sampleTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }

        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;

        return [delete];
    }
}
```

My `CustomTableViewCell`:

```
class CustomTableCell: SwipeTableViewCell {

    public var atest = UILabel()
    public var btest = UILabel()

    var animator: Any?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        atest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 , y: 2, width: 200, height: 30));

        btest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 , y: 32, width: 200, height: 30));

        self.contentView.addSubview(atest);
        self.contentView.addSubview(btest);
    }

}
```

It is working same as the first editing.

**EDIT**

`CustomTableViewCell` using `init` :

```
class CustomTableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell {

    public var atest = UILabel();
    public var btest = UILabel();

    var animator: Any?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        atest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 , y: 2, width: 100, height: 30))

        btest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20 , y: 32, width: 100, height: 30))

        self.contentView.addSubview(atest)
        self.contentView.addSubview(btest)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

change in `cellForRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = CustomTableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")

    cell.delegate = self

    cell.atest.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] + " - " + String(describing: indexPath.row)
    cell.btest.text = "another different text from an array";

    return cell;
}
```

still working same as above.

Comment: what if I have one uiview and 5 uilabels to remove? do I put it at the top of cellforrowat? Can I get a complete example for the second one? Thanks a lot

Comment: This behaves very weirdly and does more damage.  I have like 4 rows that are visible and 2 that are below the fold and I can delete the first one correctly but the 4 one still becomes the 5th one as well.  It's a reuse issue.

Comment: What damage I didn't get it. All cells are identical right ? cell count are decreasing ? 4 rows are visible and 2 are below the fold. when you delete first one then also 4 rows are visible and 1 is below the fold right ?

Comment: It deletes everything. Btw I updated the question with example code.

Comment: I'm using a plugin for swiping as mentioned in the question

Comment: " updated the deletion and used github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit to handle swiping – cdub Jul 5 at 6:16   "

Comment: I don't have awakeFromNib. It is init: override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);

Comment: my code sigaborts at the closing of the let delete braces. It runs delete, goes to the customcell class of init, runs through cellForRowAt returns to delete and crashes at the end of delete function

Comment: I don't use awake from bib

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: i am giving you the bounty for your help. I was too close to the code and it was something stupid very stupid. I had more than the 2 labels I put in the question but apparently I didn't remove them for their arrays. So silly. Thanks for all your editing.

Comment: Thank you. Glad I helped. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how your cells are being reused.  Add this line of code to your table cell class:

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

        atest.text = nil
        btest.text = nil
  }
```

Comment: y code sigaborts at the closing of the let delete braces. It runs delete, goes to the customcell class of init, runs through cellForRowAt returns to delete and crashes at the end of delete function – cdub 14 hours a

Comment: do I need deleteatrows too? I tried prepareForReuse with the remove from subview in the answer below but that didn't work it just removed everything

Comment: i appreciate your help btw

Comment: Your delete function is being called by your tableViewDelegate delete function, right? I don't see where you're actually telling your tableView to remove the cell.  I'm only seeing that you're changing the dataSource array "database".  You need to actually tell the tableView to delete one of its cells either in your tableView delegate or in your custom delete function. It looks like you have that code commented out.

Comment: It was sigabrting after returning from the delete which i thought the plugin handled it

Comment: the plugin deletes things fine if you use the defaault none custom view of a cell

Comment: Oh wait a sec... you're using SwipeKit aren't you?

Comment: Are you sure you have to call "self.database.remove(at: indexPath.row)"? I'm wondering if swipe kit already does this for you.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure. I don't call deleteRows tho at my other tableview and it works fine but i still use self.database.removeAt there